# How to create Angular 2+ toggle for multiple buttons?

Tags: angular

Hello I need to create toggle buttons, but when I click first button active class works for both element.

HTML

```
 <button [class.active]="k" (click)="toggle()">1</button>
 <button [class.active]="k" (click)="toggle()">2</button>
```

TS

```
k: boolean = false;
toggle(): void {
   this.k = !this.k;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use two different variables or an array to bind to.

**With separate variables**

```html
<button [class.active]="k1" (click)="k1 = !k1">1</button>
<button [class.active]="k2" (click)="k2 = !k2">2</button>
```

```js
k1: boolean = false;
k2: boolean = false;
```

**With array**

```html
<button [class.active]="k[0]" (click)="toggle(0)">1</button>
<button [class.active]="k[1]" (click)="toggle(1)">2</button>
```

```js
k: boolean[] = [];
toggle(index: number): void {
    this.k[index] = !this.k[index];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <button (click)="toggle($event)">1</button>
 <button (click)="toggle($event)">2</button>
```

TS:

```
toggle(event): void {
    event.target.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a unique string for separate buttons

```
<button [class.active]="button1" (click)="toggle("button1")">1</button>
<button [class.active]="button2" (click)="toggle("button2")">2</button>
```

And your function can be modified as

```
toggle(button): void {
   this.button = !this.button;
}
```

Note: I'm just providing you a idea that you should pass different values for separate buttons.